# Match all words in any order but duplicates consider as individual

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a text field which matches words in any order but when same words exist in query, it needs to give documents which has same no.of duplicates(means doesn't remove duplicate words)

```
        "match": {
            "field": {
                "operator": "and",
                "query": "2019 1 Scc 1"
            }
        }
    }
```

wrong results : 2019 6 SCC 1, 2019 5 SCC 1,SCC 1 2009 6

correct result : 1 2019 Scc 1

Comment: Have you tried adding `"minimum_should_match": "100%"` to your `match` query? (and keeping `"operator": "and"`)

Comment: It still giving wrong results (i think minimum_should_match only check minimum matching words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

match query only check the matching term by term. So it cant have a notion of term frequency.

The cool way of fulfilling your requirement could be to create a new [scripted similatiry](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html#scripted_similarity) for your field, but I'm not sure that such a script can have access to the term frequency of the request :(

But maybe a [match_phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) trick can do the job for you. Match phrase query handle request terms as a whole phrase (so it watchs token position to determine the matching). So if you configure a big slop ( like 10 ) the match query will match when every term of the request have a match in the document field (with a distinct position).

So duplicate tokens in the request needs to be find twice in the document

Here an example :

```
POST <index>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "field": {
        "slop": 10,
        "query": "2019 1 1 Scc 1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I cant assure it will work for all your use cases, but its a starting point :)

Comment: Thanks, Slop is solving duplicate issue but in highlight again its missing the duplicate.

Comment: i don't see any problem with the highlighting. Words are highlighted separately but it seems related to this https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/29561

Comment: Again match (operator - and) in highlight_query will solve highlight issue.